# View the labels of highlighted bars in Echarts even when the visibility of labels is set to false

Tags: javascript, echarts

I want to set the visibility of labels to false within Echarts, and I can achieve this with the following:

```
label: {
  show: false
}
```

However, I have another setting:

```
emphasis: {
  focus: "series"
}
```

With this, the bars in the other series also become highlighted. The issue is that I cannot see their labels.

In summary, when the visibility of labels is set to false, I want to be able to see the labels of the highlighted bars in the other series when emphasized.

I tried this:

```
label: {
  show: false,
  emphasis: {
    show: true,
    focus: "series",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to [chart events](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events) and change your [chart option](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.setOption) accordingly. [Here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&version=5.4.3&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAeBBDEDOAXMmurGAJ4gCmRA5AMYCGYVA5sAE7m0A0J6AE2aMiAbVoBZGL1i0AKgFcqM2gHUqAlXIAWClQDEOEFQGVmphdFoBdEgF8-6cjnxFUpMpRqyAbowA2SrT2jrB4VEZUhLCi_MQe6BACdACMvHHoFNR0AEaMHOkJsEJgIjEpAKwADDywAEwAzDX1dQAstXUpABy1KQ0Vva0A7B0AbFXWoR7-jDlU_m4gwHgQkDB0YKC0DhmwVAC2INqMK9HuRbAAZsD0CtG04ZF4hQl2cTse5x5JdHUvHllvLQ8gUpqQSmVRI1mnU2h1ur1qoMRrAUilmgBOCZg9AzOYLZBLFZraAbLYfBIHI4nVzxC7XW73R4QKL_UhvDwc2C2OwAbhQKH25AAwscOGAAHQwAAUtH2wDuVGAPgiMkulnoJOlIHyjH2eAAlHT6DA8GAwhEWXgAJICBCwHUcPV4CXMqK2_noIWi_KS8JgADy4Cg0GlSDd0VESB-FqettqePmbjw2mAAHciGAOEo7HZrHYDfyC_zBSKxZKZXKFeEFWA1RqtY7nUbziboGbY1bbfam_rXZb3QJPbBveX-4HgzLwwPI9Hkp3BwnZknkCn00RLgFwrn84WUMWgA) is a small example where the label visability is changed when the mouse hovers over a series item and when it stops hovering over (mouseover / mouseout):

```js
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      id: '1',
      type: 'bar',
      data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
      label: {position: 'top'},
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series',
      }
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      type: 'bar',
      data: [230, 224, 218, 150, 147, 110, 90],
      label: {position: 'top'},
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series',
      }
    }
  ]
};

myChart.on('mouseover', function(params) {
  const seriesId = params.seriesId;
  myChart.setOption({series: [{id: seriesId, label: {show: true}}]});
});

myChart.on('mouseout', function(params) {
  const seriesId = params.seriesId;
  myChart.setOption({series: [{id: seriesId, label: {show: false}}]});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://echarts.apache.org/zh/option.html#series-line.selectedMode

And try the setting with **selectedMode** and **select** like below,and make sure the selectMode must be "**series**"

```
{
    data: [11, 444, 22, 999, 777, 666, 1321],
    type: "line",
    selectedMode:'series',
    select: {
      label: {
        show: true
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I tried, but it did not work for me.

Comment: yeah....it doesnt work for hover effect